# Package Control stopped working

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

Package Control has been working fine for years on Sublime Text 3 in OS X (MacOS). However, now when I try to launch Package Control from the Command Palette, all its commands are missing.

I tried installing Package Control again using the installation code for ST3 on at https://packagecontrol.io/installation. Restarted Sublime Text but that does not help.

Downloaded `Package Control.sublime-package` and dropped it into `/Users/user/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages`
 and restarted Sublime Text but the problem persists.

Under `Sublime Text > Preference > Setting - User`, Package control is not listed under `"ignored_packages"`.

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

---

### Errors during Start up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 74, in reload_plugin
    m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
  File "./importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 678, in load_module
    exec(compile(source, source_path, 'exec'), mod.__dict__)
  File "2_bootstrap in /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 678, in load_module
    exec(compile(source, source_path, 'exec'), mod.__dict__)
  File "package_control.bootstrap in /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 678, in load_module
    exec(compile(source, source_path, 'exec'), mod.__dict__)
  File "package_control.loader in /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 57, in <module>
  File "./posixpath.py", line 83, in join
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 74, in reload_plugin
    m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
  File "./importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 678, in load_module
    exec(compile(source, source_path, 'exec'), mod.__dict__)
  File "Package Control in /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 14, in <module>
  File "./posixpath.py", line 83, in join
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
plugins loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

I had **exactly the same Type error** problem after (fresh) install on **linux Mint**. Used apt-get that installed 3103 version. Sublime suggested installing newer version at startup. After reading multitude of instructions and few re-installs I decided to get the latest version (not available with apt-get, though).

By installing the version 3143, with [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3) by Sergey, with some modifications, I got the Package control working. I didn't dig up what could have been the actual root cause, but that solved the same issue for me.

After *apt-get remove* the existing installation I got the latest software by:

```
# wget http://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3143_x64.tar.bz2
```

Unpacked to **/opt/sublime_text_3** and created a text file.

```
# nano /usr/bin/subl
```

Containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text "$@"
```

Made it executable.

```
# chmod 777 /usr/bin/subl
```

Running from command line by executing: ***subl*** starts the newly installed version.